# Save or Serialize AFNetworking operations queue?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, afnetworking

With `AFNetworking` you usually enqueue operations by doing the following:

```
[_httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```

Is there a way to serialize or save the queue so it can be resumed after App Termination?

Comment: I think you'd have to go down the route of adhering to the NSCoding protocol. I can see that AFURLConnectionOperation already does so.

Comment: Would like to see some sort of detailed example.

Comment: some tutorials: http://soff.es/archiving-objective-c-objects-with-nscoding http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/how-to-save-your-app-data-with-nscoding-and-nsfilemanager

Answer (score 2):

Actually if you look into `AFURLConnectionOperation` it implements `NSCoding` protocol, and `.m` file reflects that by implementing [`initWithCoder:`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFURLConnectionOperation.m#L797) and [`encodeWithCoder:`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFURLConnectionOperation.m#L816) methods

Although `AFHTTPClient` base class is `NSCoding` compliant too it [doesn't serialize queue itself](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFHTTPClient.m#L703)

But nothing stops you from leveraging existent codebase and extending encoding/decoding feature to serialize queue operations in you custom subclass of `AFHTTPClient`

Hope it makes sense!

Comment: Note that AFHTTPRequestOperation pauses itself when you call encodeWithCoder:! This was a big gotcha for me when I was doing this...

Comment: also, if you are targeting iOS7+ you might consider using `NSURLSession`-based AFNetworking implementation instead